# Lego world. How do they reproduce?

Tags: biology, population, reproduction

It is difficult to find statistics for the ratio of Lego men and women in the general population but from a non-scientific survey, I get the impression that Lego men vastly outnumber Lego women. Yet clearly they do reproduce. Here is a picture of a pregnant Lego woman.

[image]

Setting aside the gender ratio, it is not obvious how Lego people actually reproduce. If we look at Legoid anatomy there is no evidence of suitable appendages.

[image]

EDIT in response to the question being put on hold.

> [Help Center > Asking](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
>
> For example, questions are welcome that are about: ... 
>   How to achieve a specified effect in a defined world, including by the use of
>   technology or magic, while maintaining in-universe consistency.

In order to create a realistic Lego-based world, I wish to develop a consistent ***in-universe*** description that explains how these beings reproduce. Therefore I am not looking for an explanation that relies on human intervention. If the Legoids themselves can perform the necessary biology or technology then that is fine.

Using your knowledge of Lego, biology, pseudo-science or any other plausible mechanism (possibly including magic) can you offer a suggestion that

1. explains or suggests the mechanism of Lego reproduction.
2. explains the high preponderance of Lego males? If they were like humans we would expect a roughly 50-50 ratio.

EDIT 25 Aug 15

For these purposes, I assume that Lego people cannot see or comprehend humans - who can be considered to live in a different dimension. They see only each other and their building materials. The results of human actions (but not direct experience of humans themselves) are presumably part of their mythology and put down to natural or supernatural causes.

Comment: Could the Lego people build a factory to make more Lego people?

Comment: EVERYTHING IS AWESOME!!  (*Forgive me.  I just had to.*)

Comment: @HDE226868 - Maybe but how then do you explain the pregnant woman?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Perhaps somebody got bored.

Comment: @HDE226868 - Well that's a somewhat crude way of putting it but I'm not sure I see how.

Comment: Pregnant lego females are born/molded to look pregnant. We don't even know if there is really a baby in it, or an alien but it's surely made of plastic.

Comment: Maybe she's just fat

Comment: @Vincent - Then how do you explain this? ---> http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=lego+babies&view=detailv2&&id=FFCD71C57979B3461F02269684D326DB0C762495&selectedIndex=0&ccid=VqNoo05m&simid=608024330191569917&thid=OIP.M56a368a34e6613108264f15e51876caeH0&ajaxhist=0

Comment: @chaslyfromUK midgets pretending to be babies...  ;)

Comment: If there was a cross section of you like that your genitalia wouldn't show up either. I'm not convinced they lack them.

Comment: Considering it looks like that pony tail on the lego woman could be removed and placed on another lego person, I doubt there are even true genders in the lego population.

Comment: @Samuel - speak for yourself!

Comment: New Lego(tm) minifigs, like all Lego(tm)s, appear spontaneously in dark rooms at the bottom of unprotected human feet.  The minifigs themselves put this down to new minifigs spontaneously appearing in their midst, often with an unpleasant smell.

Comment: There are websites that answer this very question but don't search for them whilst at work.....

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When lego people expire their three core parts (head, body and legs) become disassociated. They may remain in this state in the environment for quite some time until a suitable input of energy (lightning, earthquake, storm etc) into the environment animates a new person from a suitable nearby triad of parts.

Accordingly the new person is 'animated' in adult form by a spontaneous fusing of head, body and legs. The resulting person will have an odd mix of skills and character traits inherited from the random re-mixing of old core parts. So, they exhibit Lamarckian rather than Darwinian evolution, and so don't need to be trained from scratch although some need considerable support in successfully integrating less than well matched body parts.

Lonely lego people who can't find the right soulmate are often to be found scouring the land looking for disassociated body parts which they collect together and watch over in the hope that a suitable event will cause an animation. Sadly, the results are rarely what the parts-collecter had in mind, since the life history of the individual parts is often difficult to discern.

The difference between the sexes is based purely on certain body parts having an affinity such that they are more likely all else equal to become associated. Transgender animations can and do occur though.

When the stock of disassociated parts declines below a certain level, the same energetic events that cause animation are more likely to randomly dis-associate existing people than animate new ones. Population growth thus requires the introduction of new body parts - a subject which forms a core part of all lego people's mythology and many quest stories.

For this reason very long lived lego people tend to be viewed with suspicion and resentment and may be the subject of violence (which also causes disassociation). Short lives are felt moral and honourable since it increases the stock of life skills embedded in the core parts.

Comment: That's a very well-thought-out and plausible system. However  I'm not sure how completely new lego people arise. Are you saying that new parts appear individually in the landscape or do some new people appear fully formed?

Comment: Individual body parts are scattered. I Imagined a well kept lego town with maybe a few body parts (and unused construction parts) lying about, but for the main part the unused person parts and construction parts are scattered round the hinterlands round the town. Lightning strikes in the hinterland - and sometime later a couple of new persons come wandering into town. Spontaneous disassociation could happen anywhere (which may be somewhat traumatic). Maybe body parts lying about the town only persist for a few minutes before glowing and then being transported to a random hinterland location.

Comment: I edited my answer to make the animation process clear...

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Easy answer to that one. All the LEGO minifigs that ever existed were made from already existing parts. There are no new parts. All the parts that ever will exist already do. When it comes to where the parts came from in the first place, many LEGO people believe in the Almighty "Ole Kirk Christiansen" and give him the title of the Grand Founder who dwells in the holy abode of Danemark. They sometimes call themselves `Christiansens`. Of course, from time new parts just appear in giant buckets. There are varying theories, but many feel a being named `Toysrus` is responsible.

Answer (score 17):

Lego people reproduce **asexually** through [binary fission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asexual_reproduction#Fission).  They divide in half, and each slowly grows into a new lego person.  Your "pregnant" Lego lady is actually just gorging herself in preparation for the split, to speed her re-growth.

New, never before seen Lego people are caused by errors in the regrowth process, due to the high levels of toxic chemicals and plastics in legoland.

Answer (score 8):

**They order new ones from the factory.**

Firstly, that pregnant lego woman is *clearly* photoshopped. Lego women don't *get* pregnant. If one were pregnant it's because she was made that way and she will die that way. Secondly, don't search for Lego genitalia on the internet. That's some solid internet advice; replace "Lego" with any word, you can't unsee what has been seen. It wouldn't have shown up in the picture you found in any case.

Lego people are also rather progressive, that have embraced the designer babies trend. Except their babies arrive full grown. Can you imagine how wonderful/horrifying that would be? So much they missed out on, yet, so much they got to miss out on. Lego people are like vampires, whatever age they're made at, they stay that age. Forever.

Making Lego children would be a curse on those children. They would be shorter, but still the same width (two bumps), so would live out a long and awkward life.

As for the high number of males (no, they're not made in China), construction and engineering are massive industries for Lego people. As with humans, they are still very male dominated fields. As the Lego people have higher need for doctors, scientists, and athletes the number of female Lego people will increase.

Comment: I disagree with your last paragraph in its gender role bias, but I enjoy how your answer is wonderfully grounded in reasonable Lego logic. +1

Comment: @Marion It's not prescribing gender roles, so it's not a bias. It's explaining the fact that construction and engineering are currently fields with a vast majority of men compared to women, that's just a fact, not a endorsement ("male dominated" means mostly made up by men, not that men excel at the work where women don't). It explains the OP's observation that Lego populations seem to be mostly men.

Answer (score 4):

Lego people, despite their appearance, are genderless.

You feed two of them a brick, love hearts will appear on top of their head, they will get close to each other… a small Lego kid will spawn nearby, and also an experience orb which you might (and should) collect.

[image: Minecraft villagers breeding]

Yes, [that's Minecraft](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Breeding), but it's as Lego as it can get.

Comment: Yes, but that *still* doesn't explain the pregnant Lego woman! That is what is worrying me. I suppose the love hearts would work but we still have the problem of pregnancy and birth.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK that's fake, she's just trying to get your seat on the bus.

Answer (score 4):

We've long known thát Lego people don't reproduce in the same way non-Lego humans do (see rumguff's excellent answer), for all the ages that have passed in Legoland, no one ever knew why. Now that another age has passed, even since this query was asked, new revelations out of Legoland confirm the answer that ***modern*** Lego people  -- *Lego minifigurae manihabiles* -- **do in fact reproduce**, just not in the way we might expect.

**First some history:**  We know from the most ancient of records to be found in Legoland (discovered recently in the Bookshop, set 10270), that there were, in fact, *three races of Lego people*.

In those days there were giants in the land...  Back in the earliest epochs of Legoland history, all Lego people were big. *Lego magnitestae*, the so-called "big heads".

[image]

And as we can see, Lego people at that time did in fact reproduce and grow old. During this archaic epoch, certain environmental factors spelled the downfall of the "big heads". First, and although we have little material evidence from this time in history, we do have tantalising hints of multi-limbed and tentacle-limbed monstrosities being born. The relative sparsity of basic building materials in the archaic age also spelled doom for these giants, as even a family of five simply could not procure enough bricks or base plates or roofing shingles to create even a modest cottage, to say nothing of banding together in communities.

And so the archaic age with its reclusive giants came to an end, outcompeted by the most unlikely of evolutionary freaks.

During the short lived middle epoch of Legoland history, a new kind of Lego person was created from the potential brick, *Lego minifigurae rigidae*. These bizarre people were much shorter than the "big heads", and were, in many ways, more frightening than the great monsters of old.

[image]

With their expressionless faces and immobile trunks, yet somehow able to braid their hair and wear their caps, they dominated Legoland for a short time. Yet somehow they were able to rebuild Lego civilisation, undoubtedly drawing on the ruins of the "big heads'" earlier attempts.

[image]

Their time of dominance was short lived, however, as the middle epoch evolved into the younger epoch and the rise to dominance of the minifigure proper was accomplished.

From the medieval period...

[image]

to the space age...

[image]

Lego people kept advancing, but one thing neither the rigid nor the articulated kinds of people could do was reproduce -- unlike the big heads, we see no children in these later epochs of Legoland history!

Not even the short-lived evolutionary throwbacks that arose at this time, *Lego magnatesta basica*, had children.

[image]

And at the time this query was written, that was the state of things.

But since that time, as was mentioned earlier, new revelations have come out of Legoland. There are now known to be *Lego children and Lego babies*!

[image]
[image]

It's unclear how they are formed, as their brick matrices vary from the normal, though it is known that, as with adult Lego people, children and babies are brought fourth from that mysterious place called the Brick Box, having been formed from the primordial brick. Some believe that Lego pediatricians have something to do with the process, but there is no clear evidence for this.

At least this much is clear: as it was towards the beginning, it has always been the Plan for Lego people to live in family relationship and exhibit varying ages among individuals of society. It is simply not until the modern epoch that Bill and Mary's descendants have been given this gift by their Creator.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

### LEGO people don't reproduce.

There's a **finite** number of lego people and parts and all new LEGO people are simply made at a LEGO people assembling building from the disassembled parts of former LEGO people. These parts are usually kept in a giant yellow container curiously called "minifig bucket."

All LEGO people require a triune of parts to be considered alive. The Trunk, the Torso, and the Pineapple ( also known as the yellow head cylinder ). It is only when these three parts are connected that you get a sentient LEGO person.

### LEGO people also *do not die*.

Their pieces do age, their colors do fade... but they don't actually DIE in our sense of the word.

You could compare LEGO to a three-celled organism that only have higher-level functions when all three cells are connected to one another.

Occasionally an accident will happen like a LEGO person hanging onto a helicopter while their torso is clicked into a particularly stubborn pip. When their body is separated, they immediately lose all sentience. While it is possible to put the pieces back together again, once disconnected, the exposure of the innards of the LEGO minifig parts erases all memories and therefore what you could call consciousness so there's really no point.

Effectively they're dead... despite their really being no degradation of the pieces... so their pieces are simply collected and sent to the big minifig bucket in the SKY ( Special Kollection Yard )

When pieces are randomly matched ( or LEGO people are *birthed* ) all variables are randomized and they gain a completely random personality.

### Finite number of LEGO people and the grand purpose

There is a finite number of LEGO people. It will never go higher. It will only gradually get lower over many millions of years as parts wear out and pieces no longer stay together. However, there's a MASSIVE glut of extra parts that have never been used, so that isn't a problem.

### Beliefs

There have been some LEGO people who adhere to the teaching of scientism that have proposed bonding pieces together as a means of gaining true immortality, but there is a rather vocal group of religious individuals who feel this is not part of the master builder's plan and that the natural order of disassembly and reassembly is the natural way of things. They fear that permanence is not the LEGO way and goes against their purpose of existence as flexible and modular beings as purposed by the Grand Designer.

They feel that followers of scientism are trying to become *The Builder* themselves. Many of these scientists don't believe in *The Builder* and want to believe that LEGO parts came from millions of years of iteration. They refused to believe that their world or their pieces were the product of a **designer** and feel that their world was not designed, but came about by random accidents in what they call the *Big Billund Theory*. Although most LEGO people accept most of facts of "Big Billund Factory" the followers of Scientism believe that no *being* conceived or initiated the "Big Billund Factory" but rather that it came about by accident.

Most LEGO people, OTOH, believe that there was a "First Cause" and attribute it to the "Grand Designer". To many LEGO people, they give this "First Cause" a name. They believe they this Designer is not made of the same materials as them... and use the "Holy Manual" as proof of the Designer's existence. A few call themselves followers of *Ole Kirk Christiansen*... who occasionally intervenes from a spiritual place called "Denmark". Followers of Scientism say this place doesn't exist and since they can't see *Ole Kirk* he doesn't exist. As you imagine, it's quite the problem and has caused wars.

Many LEGO people point to the intricate designs as impossible to have come about by mere chance and think the LEGO followers of scientism are somewhat of a cult and as such dismiss them as crackpots. As you can imagine, most LEGO people believe in a Great Designer, though some believe in a pantheon of Great Builders as opposed to one Original Designer.

### History

Note that long ago, LEGO society didn't really exist as minifigs regularly removed the heads and torsos of others randomly, while sleeping... or just out of curiosity. In addition, they sometimes did it to themselves. They could not build a society in those days, and as such were more akin to minifigs wandering in a wilderness of spare pieces.

### Conclusion

#### In the end, LEGO don't reproduce. They simply replace and reuse.

Answer (score 2):

Now that this question has been resurrected and returning to my own question after several years, I can see an answer that didn't occur to me before.

I originally said

> ... it is not obvious how Lego people actually reproduce. If we look at
>   Legoid anatomy there is no evidence of suitable appendages.

However I overlooked the fact that Lego people have a stud on the top of their head and sockets in their feet. This means that a suitable connection could be made after all.

Answer (score 2):

They don't, at least in any sense we'd recognize. Their reality follows the fundamental principle that **function follows form**.

What this means is that when pieces are assembled in the form of a person, it functions as a person. Minifig pieces are best for this, obviously, but any collection of pieces assembled into the form of head, body and limbs will also function as a person—though not as well, hence why they display erratic and often antisocial behavior.

Due to mystical forces, the collection of pieces in their world is often changing, allowing/forcing them to reassemble each other into new and different forms with new and different functions.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of Rumguff's answer. A higher intelligence makes them. They have some myths regarding this, and some atheist lego people believe in pure spontaneous generation.

Most lego people have little memory of their first moments of life, but under hypnotic regression many remember an impossibly gigantic lego person, with jointed arms and legs, assembling them. The idea that lego people are created by one or more giants is actually their most popular myth.

Their own scientists simple have no idea about how they are born and offer no answer. The appearance of new people is simply a fact that everyone accepts as normal.