# Russian Dolls - How do they reproduce?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, population, reproduction

**Warning** picture showing dissected Russian Doll

> [image]

**My theory**

I believe that Russian Dolls reproduce asexually. They are born pregnant. At the time of birth, the outer doll dies. What is now the outer doll grows until it reaches full size at which point it gives birth and dies. The birth process is simple - the outer doll simply splits in half around its middle. A new inner doll forms at the same time.

**The problem**

My theory would mean that the population could only stay the same or decrease. In fact accidents would mean that the population would decrease until the species became extinct.

**Question**

How can I resolve this problem and allow increase in population whilst still preserving my theory as much as possible?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89190/discussion-on-question-by-chasly-from-uk-russian-dolls-how-do-they-reproduce).

Comment: Related, but not a dupe: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/22876/21222. Interestingly also authored by you. +1 to both.

Comment: related: https://www.livescience.com/49766-baby-pregnant-twins.html

Comment: I only knew of "black widows" so far, didn't know "white orphans" also exist!!!

Comment: Your theory sounds very similar to Preformationism: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preformationism
The population number could increase with twin dolls inside a mother doll.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Fertile dolls have noses which grow when detached, feeding on the discarded outer shell. Most farm dolls have the nose neutered away to save on resources and control the overall doll count of each ranch.

Comment: I have no idea which question you are answering.

Comment: Me neither, but I love it.

Comment: Now I think about it, this is the most plausible answer so far. I think some details are missing but I can see how it would work. P.S. I assume that by 'neutering away', you mean that the outer doll has its nose somehow cauterised to prevent it reproducing and that this will cause it to put all of its resources into growing. (?) Maybe some more detail would be helpful.

Comment: Yes chasly that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: This would explain why the dolls don't have sticking-out noses when on sale.

Comment: +1 for supporting some Pinocchio theories. The dolls noses grow as the lie about the dolls being just, well, wooden dolls, continues to exist

Answer (score 333):

Through selective breeding and misplaced import laws, we only ever get to see Russian dolls that are "aesthetically pleasing".

In the wild, it is relatively common to get a "double-yolker" - that is, sometimes when the outer layer dies, there are 2, or perhaps 3 dolls inside.

Since these dolls are often a little misshapen when compared to the outer layer, they never get selected for sale, but are instead kept for breeding. It typically takes a few generations before the descendants of one of these dolls achieves the aesthetically pleasing shape that consumers have come to expect.

Comment: Gross! I love it : )

Comment: You answered this so smoothly its hard to tell if I'm on worldbuilding or some other wordly bio.se.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I'm not even sure that double-yolk twins would stay misshapen for long or, if they were, that they they would pass the characteristic on to their offspring. In any case this seems like a convincing answer.

Comment: I would think it's preferable for the breeders if the double-yolkedness isn't hereditary...

Comment: In fact, variable-yolking evolved as a population-regulating mechanism: the more well-fed and otherwise healthy a doll is, the more likely she is to produce a larger collection (is "collection" the proper group term for dolls?); when times are leaner, you get more singletons; over time, this makes the population tend to stabilize. The twist is that this mechanism has a long lead-time, as each doll fissions several generations before she is born, based on the nutrition, etc., passed inward from her great-great-babushka. So the cyclical feedback patterns get complex.

Comment: So that would mean the aesthetically pleasing dolls are actually the weak ones, doomed to disappear after a few generations, while the ugly double-yolker are the ones keeping the species alive. (it does contradict evolution, doesn't it?)

Comment: @PierreArlaud aesthetically pleasing doesn't mean better in terms of evolution. Skinnier women are most commonly perceived as the "most aesthetically pleasing" (models etc.), while slight fatness (probably there is better term for this) and wide hips are considered better for reproduction. Moreover, the ones who were born "aesthetically pleasing" still have a chance of having double-yolked offspring

Comment: "pure" breed dogs are the result of selective breeding by humans, and are often really poorly suited to survival - humans have worked _against_ natural evolution to encourage the traits that they want - it's the same with the dolls

Comment: Which of course means most factory farmed dolls are the result of generations of enforced relative starvation to discourage the production of doubles.

Comment: Joined this community only to comment here. You had me at "double-yolker", that's so unexpected, weird and hilarious.

Comment: This is the best answer to a best question I've ever seen here.

Answer (score 135):

In the deepest, darkest, hidden places in the forest dwell the **Queen Dolls**.

Rarely seen, these creatures resemble a normal Russian Doll only at the tops of their vast, misshapen bodies - their lower halves more closely resemble a nightmarish wooden bee hive.

Riddled with thousands of cells, they disgorge the normal Russian Dolls commonly found in the forests. But for every 1000 of these normal Russian Dolls a juvenile Queen will emerge.

This instar queen will then scuttle off on their many jointed legs to find a new nest.

There are myths and legends of a *King Doll*, but no sightings have yet been reliably reported.

Comment: I shall now try to erase this horrible vision from my imagination!

Comment: Horrifying!  I imagined a Doll King = Rat King kind of scenario...

Comment: I saw this movie! It had Sigourney Weaver in it =)...

Comment: I'm imagining something like an upside down Suriname toad

Comment: Tsarina dolls, surely... ?

Comment: @colmde of course! I shall have a word with my translator...

Answer (score 100):

Actually, there is an organism on earth that is vaguely similar to the Russian dolls that you describe. The [*volvox*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volvox):

[image: volvox]

Individual volvox cells, a kind of freshwater algae, reproduce in the conventional way (more or less), however, they also collect into spherical colonies (called volvocates, I think) with a tiny opening at one end. These spheres can reproduce by internal budding, with immature spheres growing within the body of the 'mother' sphere. Then at some point, the mother turns itself inside-out by inverting itself through the opening, releasing the 'daughter' spheres into the wild. The point where the daughter sphere connected with this interior of the mother becomes the opening of the daughter sphere (sort of like a navel in mammals). The cells that formerly composed the mother sphere don't simply die, however. Most of them are absorbed by one of the daughter spheres.

And yes, 'granddaughter' spheres can start to develop within the daughter spheres before 'birth'/'hatching'. In the following photo, you can see a mother colony in the process of disintegration, releasing it's daughters, which in turn have daughters already developing:

[image: granddaughters]
<sup>Photo credit: [www.microscopy-uk.org.uk](http://www.microscopy-uk.org.uk/mag/artdec03/volvox.html)</sup>

Now, there are two differences between the volvox and your Russian dolls:

1. The 'birth' event doesn't lead to complete death of the 'mother'.
2. More than one daughter born per 'birth' event.

The first feature can be achieved by your dolls if the 'mother' dolls can reform somehow. Perhaps the 'head' can reattach to the 'tail' and continue living. After consuming enough nutrients from the environment, they could even begin the process of internal budding again. Or perhaps the daughters simply consume the mother's material, giving them a early boost in life.

The second feature can be achieved by simply dividing multiple times. Russian dolls have multiple layers inside at varying levels of size, but all are viable. When a large doll splits, a medium one emerges and splits, then a small one emerges and splits, then a smaller one, until there several offspring. Combined withe the above, you could have a burgeoning population of Russian dolls (*Matryoshkavox*?)

Comment: Damn you, nature! Stop stealing our ideas!

Comment: @T.Sar It's Rule 34 of reality: If you can think of a reproductive scheme, nature's done it somewhere.

Comment: Any idea if the growth process is so slow that sometimes the daughter spheres themselves can start growing grandaughter spheres before breakout?

Comment: @JeopardyTempest I had to do a bit of digging around the internet to confirm, but yes, that's possible. See my update.

Comment: Funny, the first things I thought of were [diatoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatom#Reproduction_and_cell_size), with some equally weird algal reproduction.

Comment: @Sparhawk I wasn't all that familiar with it before, but, indeed, diatom reproduction does share a bit in common with the Russian dolls. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Although my biology degree is some 30y ago now, I have to question this bit:

> The cells that formrly composed the mother sphere don't  simply die, however. Most of them are absorbed by one of the  daughter spheres.

Comment: @LiamProven Thanks for your reply. I *don't* have a biology degree. I vaguely remembered this from some book I read that described the volvox life cycle. IIRC the were described as somewhat similar to sponges in that individual cells could be separated from the colony and reintegrated later. I might be entirely wrong on this point though. I'll do some searching later today and see if I can substantiate that particular claim.

Comment: I was thinking aphids - they are born with eggs already formed inside of them.

Comment: @Baldrickk Yes and aphids also have a dual reproductive system (sexual during lean times / winter, parthenogenic during warm periods to capitalize on available food as quickly as possible while it lasts). My reading about the volvox suggests it's dual reproductive system evolved for the same purpose (heat shock stimulates sexual reproduction, likely in preparation for a drought). There are definitely some parallels.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Not for a moment saying that you should have to participate!

My position is basically that Volvox are very much plants. They don't _eat_ as such. They absorb CO₂ and other trace nutrients and they photosynthesize and that's all. 

So the ruptured "mother" ball's cells can't be eaten and can't become parts of other colonies. Colonies grow by cell division, not incorporating outsiders. They can't.

After the ball ruptures, it can't swim any more, so that's it. It dies.

Comment: @LiamProven I wasn't thinking about the mother cells being eaten by daughters (although I did mention that possibility in the case of the Russian dolls), so much as the mother cells joining the intercellular matrix of daughter colonies. However, I have been unable to find anything directly stating if this is even possible or if they simply die. I've asked about this specific point over on [bio.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/81091/volvox-cellular-reintegration) and I welcome your input!

Comment: @p.s.w.g Great question -- upvoted! The thing is that the cells in a volvox are interlinked because they grew together. They are all descendants of a single progenitor cell. (Like, for example, a human.) They can't integrate extra members later. Comparison: a human chimera, formed from 2 merged embryos, contains 2 dissimilar genomes... but add another individual's cells & that person must be on immunity-suppressants for the rest of their life. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_(genetics)

Answer (score 42):

**Regenerate the top part.**

The splitting doesn't actually kills the doll - just its bottom half.

The bottom half becomes a nest for the little doll that was gestating on the inside of the "mother doll" for a bit, until it can go around hunting for cookie crumbles for itself.

The upper part, on the other hand, shrinks a bit in size and regenerates. After some time passes, it can produce a new doll on its now-empty insides.

This way, the doll population will increase steadily, as most other living beings. They would only truly die from old age, predators, accidents or kid-induced acts of doll terrorism.

Comment: This means that the head ends repeatedly go through this process. I'm not sure how your theory explains many layers of doll.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I'll explain it a bit better.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK there!

Comment: @chaslyfromUK You could have it alternate between the top and bottom.

Comment: This sounds a little like planarian (flatworm) reproduction. Cut a flatworm in half, the head grows a new tail and the tail grows a new head. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planarian#Regeneration

Answer (score 37):

Budding and out-growing.

**Budding**: each outer doll, once in a while, produces a bud, which in this case is a tiny Russian doll. Once it detaches from the mother body, it starts living on its own.

**Out-growing**: once the doll has eaten enough, it grows, on its outer, a new shell. Think of it like the trees growing each year adding a layer to their bark. At the end, being made of wood, it's perfectly reasonable for a Russian doll to grow like a tree does.

Comment: So your theory is almost the opposite of mine? The centre of a tree/doll dies and the bark/outer-layer is alive? It hadn't occurred to me that the dolls might be a kind of tree and the faces and clothing on them some kind of mimicry. Perhaps while alive they have roots emerging from the base and these are removed when the dolls are prepared for sale.

Comment: I've been thinking about this. It actually makes more sense than my original idea that they are animal based (sort of like loofahs that most people think are some kind of animal sponge but are actually vegetable). It seems worth submitting your idea as a separate question as it doesn't answer mine  (hence I'm reluctant to accept it as correct) but proposes an alternative. Do you wish to do this or shall I?

Comment: This I think makes good sense.  The essential nature of the Russian Doll is, after all, wood; and it is the way of plants to bud from time to time.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, I don't see a question in my answer, so I wouldn't know what to ask, and in your question the assumption that Russian dolls are animals is not explicit. Moreover, also yeasts (which are not animal nor plants) reproduce by budding.

Comment: Also, @chaslyfromUK, this explains the many sizes of Russian Dolls one can find. Some are simply ginormous, and must have been growing layer upon layer for ages!

Comment: @L.Dutch - I think the phrase, *"Russian Dolls are born pregnant."* contains enough information from which to infer an animal origin.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, pregnancy is typical of mammals, which do reproduce sexually. In the same question you also talk about asexual reproduction. So, no, it's not clear that you are talking about animals.

Comment: The usage is pretty common for other species, e.g. *"Aphids, tiny insects found the world over, are “essentially born pregnant,” says Ed Spevak, curator of invertebrates at the St. Louis Zoo."* https://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2013/09/animals-sex-reproduction-age-mating/ -  Conversely I am not aware that the term 'pregnant' has ever been used by anyone to describe vegetation.

Answer (score 25):

There is one flaw with the OP's theory: Russian *Matroshkiya* dolls do not die when split.  Anywhere that these dolls are found, over time it may be noticed that their population increases.

This occurs with human assistance.  A doll grows to a certain size, spawning dolls inside itself which grow with it. When a doll reaches maximum size, it ceases growing, as does its offspring and their offspring.  This is where human intervention comes in.

Where humans exist, Matroshkiya dolls have evolved to have patterning pleasing to humans. Humans, seeing a doll with a pleasing pattern, split them along the line of weakness around their middle, releasing their offspring, then they rejoin them.  When the Matroshkiya dolls are rejoied, much as a grafted branch,  they do not die.  If the doll's offspring has been removed, then the offspring resumes growing, and the outer doll produces a new offspring which grows to fill the available space, producing its own offspring as it grows.

Comment: They can do so by nature as well, but the human support makes the process easier and less painful. This is why dolls tamed humans. The main drawback of that is that mainly non-cautious human offspring (called babies or infants) allow this process. The adults tend to ensure that all Matryoshkas go back to their position, thus preventing the reproduction. BTW I have two Matryoshkas. One consists of 5, the other of 6 dolls. This is apparent proof that the Matryoshka doesn't die and the number of dolls vary depending of age. It shouldn't be surprising, that the 6 dolls Matryoshka is larger (older)

Comment: This hypothesis is confirmed by [*Dimiter Inkiow*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimitar_Inkiow)'s first book, written in 1975. I don't know the book's name in English, but in Spanish it's *Matrioska*, in German it's *Die Puppe die ein Baby haben wollte* and in Bulgarian it's *Куклата, която искаше да си има бебе*.
BTW, only female Matroshkiya dolls can reproduce (with help of a human mastercraft). Males, which can be identified by a large moustach, can't.

Comment: @J.A.I.L. _"Males, which can be identified by a large moustach"_ ~ there aren't any male Matroshkiya dolls, those are just unfortunate females with a hormone imbalance.

Answer (score 24):

I'm Russian, I know the answer, but do not tell it to anyone else. The point is. that we should not stop at one pregnancy for a doll. If the outer doll is pregnant, so does the inner one (this is what we see on the picture). That leads us to an infinite series of pregnant dolls of different sizes, thus extinction is not possible for these strange creatures (see below). The awful part starts when we start to think what is being sold on the market. I think it is a dead Russian Doll, so someone deliberately kills the infinite pregnant creature, cuts it apart wash the guts out. During the washing smallest dolls are lost. We only can hope that they (the smallest) still can be alive somewhere (I think they are), and in the millions of years, they will grow significantly big to conquer the WORLD.  If you ask me why they are made of wood, I will answer that trees are made of wood, but for some reason, you do not ask me why is it so...

Comment: Yep.  It's dolls all the way down.

Comment: It's Red Alert 2, but with dolls

Answer (score 22):

It's self-evident all births are cesarean, at worst a little masking tape & mum's fine, in a few months she's ready to give birth again.

Answer (score 11):

The OP's growth assumption is incorrect.

There are two types of Russian Doll.

1. **Top growers**
   The top growers expand their top halves while the lower halves remain the same size.
2. **Bottom growers**

The bottom growers expand their lower halves while the upper halves remain the same size.

When the top half of Top Grower expands too large it pops off and joins the equivalent lower half from the Bottom Grower to form a hybrid doll. They continue to do the same until they reach a maximum size, **after which they stop growing completely and die when split**

Occasionally a Russian Doll can develop a type of cancer where they continue to grow uncontrollably. There is a theory that the Earth and Moon are remnants of an ancient dinosaur Russian Doll that outgrew gravitational forces, leaving the Moon as a Top Half and our world as a Bottom Half.

Answer (score 8):

Your theory is correct and they do become extinct, but **Geppetto** builds more in his secret bio-woodshop-laboratory. Along with the good fairy to bring the dolls to life, they cornered the market and made billions.

Accidents such as the discarded-wooden-parts-wanting-to-become-a-real-child incident were covered by the government and became folk tales.

Answer (score 8):

### Each layer is actually two organisms

The top halves and bottom halves of the dolls are the species' equivalent for male and female organisms; when they join together they remain together until the child is formed, protecting and feeding it internally.

Matrioshkas always produce children in male-female pairs; siblings can be identified because the colors and designs (formed partially through genetic influence but also through prenatal conditions) line up.  In the wild, this serves to prevent inbreeding; Matryoshkas instinctively avoid combining with partners whose pattern lines up with their own, but when humans kill them for sale they generally discard the outer parent, keeping only the nested siblings.  It is not uncommon, however, for prenatal Matrioshkas to mate with their siblings prior to birth; and if the outer parent has enough food multiple generations of Matrioshkas can form inside a single body.  However this means that the further in one goes, the more inbred the Matrioshkas tend to be, which is why birth defects are not uncommon in the smaller layers.

Comment: This is highly plausible. There are mites that mate before birth, Adactylidium, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adactylidium

Comment: I'm glad I scrolled all the way down.  I like this even better than the top answer.

Answer (score 6):

**Wicker Dolls**

Russian dolls actually reproduce by consuming the ashes of burnt animals and/or people. Biomass in this form is reconstituted into another doll, which the parent doll then splits open to disgorge.

The exported Russian dolls you see are actually produced by small isolated Slavic pagan communities residing in extremely remote areas. These communities are the only ones that know the secret of the nesting doll, as they possess and watch over the really big "brood mother" dolls. These dolls are unique in that they are capable of reproducing multiple times unlike their "children".

On May Day every year, the pagan villagers young and old gather around maypoles to dance, sing, copulate and otherwise celebrate fertility in their own ways. They conclude the festivities with a special ceremony which all attend in symbolic costume and make up. A virgin sacrifice is tied to a stake, doused with oil and placed within the brood mother doll. The sacrifice is then lit afire, the mother doll closed and sealed as the community sing songs of praise to Mother Nature. This they believe will ensure the climate will always be favourable and the harvest always good.

Several days later, the villagers then return to find within the matriarch doll the smaller ones we foreigners are familiar with

Answer (score 5):

Two-stage reproduction:  In the first stage, the Doll "bulbs" into two (or occasionally more) mirrored/symmetrical copies, like a daffodil or an onion does.

It is this second form which is fertilised from an outside source, and then grows a new first-stage Doll inside it, eventually cracking open around the middle.

Answer (score 4):

> My theory would mean that the population could only stay the same or
>   decrease. In fact accidents would mean that the population would
>   decrease until the species became extinct.

Your theory is mistaken. In fact if it were not for the harsh Russian winter and predation by humans, a single Russian Doll "stem mother" or *fundatrix* could produce billions of descendants in one season, all of which would be clones of herself. Their ability to give birth by parthenogenesis means that population can increase exponentially without the need for the presence of male Russian Dolls. To this already formidable capacity to breed must be added the strange phenomenon of ["telescoping of generations"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_generations): Russian Doll nymphs can be born pregnant with an embryo that is itself pregnant.

Fortunately for humanity this Doll population explosion is limited by environmental factors (and according to some observers, voracious cannibalism). The coming of winter both kills off much of the swarm and induces hormonal changes in the surviving Dolls, causing a new generation to be born that contains both males and females. The males are genetically identical to their mothers apart from having one fewer sex chromosomes. Both the males and females of this generation are of the rarely seen sexual type of Russian Doll. Like aphids, mayflies and many other insects, the sexual forms die soon after mating. Their corpses can be recognised by the lack of any mouthparts in their colourful "painted" carapaces, and of course the presence of the sexual organs. Their shed shells fetch high prices in the more specialised type of souvenir shop.

Answer (score 4):

I always believed that the dolls you can buy are all dead (presumably killed by the ruthless doll farmers and poachers). The ones in the wild are soft and cuddly, but when they die, their skins harden into something similar to wood. When discovered by humans, make-up is applied to make them more aesthetically pleasing.

As for reproduction, my belief is that the inner most doll is a newly formed one. It grows up somewhat hollow, and eventually grows a new doll inside itself (a little like a tree forms a bud, which turns into a flower or fruit or whatever). As the (now) innermost doll baby grows, it stretches all the other dolls outside it and they get bigger and bigger. However, the outer-most doll is the oldest, and it cannot withstand the stretching forever, and eventually splits around the middle (which kills it) and it falls off, leaving the next largest to be the outermost doll. Somewhat sadly for the dolls, they only see daylight when they're 'next in line' to die.

Edit: As for propagation of the species and avoiding dying out... How about twins? Every once in a while, two buds form in the centre, and gradually form dolls around them both. As the outer layers age, eventually the 'single' layers break off, revealing two (now separate) dolls.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure how this explains them not dying out.

Answer (score 3):

I was under the impression that the outermost doll was the mother and that the inner dolls were children of varying sizes. The split halves of the dolls are an evolutionary trait that allowed mothers to protect their children, guaranteeing a higher survival rate to adulthood. Alternatively, the mother can sacrifice herself to predators by ejecting the offspring so that they can flee. In this case, the second doll becomes the new mother. Otherwise, offspring move out once they are mature enough. Nesting dolls are, by default, hollow, but we are used to seeing them layered, and empty nesting dolls are mistaken for a different species.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, No Good! If you have a moment, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) useful. [Here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6388) is a meta post on the culture and style of Worldbuilding.SE, just to help you understand our scope and methods, and how we do things here. Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

#### Their reproduction cycle includes a symbiotic/parasitic/viral phase

Just like a Terran virus (a virion, actually), they can transfer their "DNA/RNA" (their "building plan") into an organism which then becomes a host. This host, of suitable, then produces new Russian Dolls. Naturally, of all the infected organisms, many are dead-end or intermediate hosts, which do not reproduce Russian Dolls.

Just like Terran aphids, they pursue more than a single reproductive strategy ("born pregnant").

Surprisingly, several Russian Dolls can simultaneously infect the same host, leading to a fusion of different "building plans" to produce, through meiosis, offspring which is potentially genetically diverse from the parent virions.

Naturally, mutation also increases genetic diversity of the Russian Doll population.

Some hosts actually have a symbiotic relationship with the Russian Doll species. Their infection stays at a level where the life of the host is not threatened, but allows the host to actually make a living by selling newly spawned Russian Dolls. As Monty Wild observed, Russian Dolls have evolved to be pleasant to the host of predilection species.

Surprisingly, there actually *is* a Terran species whose viral reproductive phase is exactly like that of the Russian Doll: the **Матрёшка** ("Matryoshka Doll").

The Матрёшка, which also evolved to pleasant to the host species (the so-called homo sapiens), infects hosts *optically*. The "building plan" is injected into the host's brain through optical pathways ("eyes"), and possibly causes Матрёшка reproduction, if the host is suitable. The suitability of a host seems to correlate with its woodworking skills. Mutation and meiosis are also at work here, increasing genetic diversity and supporting Матрёшка evolution.

Матрёшка are also born pregnant.

Sources:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virus
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_(biology)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphid
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiosis
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_synthesis_(20th_century)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_sapiens
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodworking

Answer (score 3):

I point you to the common aphid. They are known to reproduce asexually. In fact, they are all female. Sex just gets in the way of creating more aphids. That's why an infestation happens so quickly.  And much like tribbles they are born pregnant. In fact, they have granddaughters developing inside their unborn daughters all the way down like Russian dolls.

However, when food becomes scarce in the fall this triggers the birth of males, and then they produce sexually and lay eggs.

Russian dolls do much the same, at some point in the season, the inner most dull is a Male, but it cracks open immeadiately releasing spores into the wind for fertilizing russian doll eggs, likewise at the end of the season the dolls that end their chain with a female, cracks open revealing a clutch of eggs to survive the harsh russian winter. The Male spores land on and fertilize the egg clutches, and thus there is a genesis of more Russian dolls.

The russian dolls that are smart and strong enough to survive to the breeding season guarantee that the breeding population is the most fit of the other russian dolls.